# Select dataframe slice using condition on a separate dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to select a slice from a column in a dataframe based on a condition applied to a second, same-sized dataframe.  I do not use column names and therefore need a solution that (I think) uses iloc.

Here is my  code:

```
import pandas as pd

permnos = pd.read_csv('Ranks.csv')
total_cols = len(permnos.columns)

pntls = permnos.copy(deep=True)

for i in range(total_cols):
    for j in range(pntls.iloc[:,i].count()):
        pntls.iloc[j,i] = (j+1)/pntls.iloc[:,i].count()

print((pntls.iloc[:,0] > 0.1) & (pntls.iloc[:,0] <= 0.2))

#print(permnos.iloc[(pntls.iloc[:,0] > 0.1) & (pntls.iloc[:,0] <= 0.2), 0])
```

The dataframe `permnos` contains identifiers (5 digit numbers) with columns of various row lengths.  In each column, these identifiers are sorted (done in a separate program) from "best" to "worst".  The for loop writes the dataframe `pntls` such that a percent rank is created for each element in each column of `permnos` based on position.  That is, the values in each column of `pntls` range from ~0 to 1, in ascending order.  Through this step, all is well.

In my line currently commented out (the problem), I am trying to print the elements in column 0 of `permnos` for which the values in column 0 of `pntls` are greater than 0.1 and less than or equal to 0.2.  [Note: Once I figure out how to actually select the desired elements, I have code that will use .tolist() to add the slice to a list; I think I have that bit sorted out if I can get the slice].  The currently commented out line yields:

> NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an 
>   integer type is not available

To give an example of my desired output, suppose that in column 0 of `pntls` the values between 0.1 and 0.2 are in rows 5 through 8, inclusive.  Then I'd like to return the slice from `permnos` of `permnos.iloc[5:9, 0]`.

Is it possible to "communicate" between the two dataframes?  If so, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "communicate" between the two dataframes is not possible, because different objects. But if same length and same index is possible create mask in one `df` and apply it to second one.

Also is possible filtering if different indexes (but same lengths), then is necessary add `.values` to `mask` like `permnos[m.values].iloc[:, 0]` for boolean numpy array.

```
pntls  = pd.DataFrame({'B':[.2,.1,.12,.4,.15,.4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (pntls)
      B  C  D  E
0  0.20  7  1  5
1  0.10  8  3  3
2  0.12  9  5  6
3  0.40  4  7  9
4  0.15  2  1  2
5  0.40  3  0  4
```

---

```
m = (pntls.iloc[:,0] > 0.1) & (pntls.iloc[:,0] <= 0.2)
print (m)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: B, dtype: bool

permnos  = pd.DataFrame({'a':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'b':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'c':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'd':[5,3,6,9,2,4]})

print (permnos)
   a  b  c  d
0  7  1  1  5
1  8  3  3  3
2  9  5  5  6
3  4  7  7  9
4  2  1  1  2
5  3  0  0  4
```

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then select:

```
df = permnos[m].iloc[:, 0]
print (df)
0    7
2    9
4    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Use `loc` and select columns names by slicing:

```
df = permnos.loc[m, permnos.columns[0]]
print (df)
0    7
2    9
4    2
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Your original solution return:

```
df = permnos.iloc[m, 0]
print (df)
```

> NotImplementedError: iLocation based boolean indexing on an integer type is not available

Comment: Thank you - the line df = permnos[m].iloc[:, 0] was particularly useful.  Separate question (I searched to no avail):  How did you highlight the error message so I can edit my original post to include this highlighting?